# How to store STDIN from text file

Tags: c, fgets

I need to read in words from a text file and then count the occurrences of each word but I can't figure out how to store the words in a variable.

I read the code in using fgets, and then i can print it using printf. However when I try to store the character array in a different array that I can use to compare the character arrays later, i keep getting seg faults. How can I go about saving the character array "line" in a different array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE  500    
#define MAXWORDS 1000 


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
   char line[MAXSIZE];
   char line1[MAXWORDS][MAXSIZE];
   int i,j,k;
   int count = 0;


   while ( fgets ( line, MAXSIZE, stdin ) != NULL ) {
    printf("%s", line);


    strcpy(line1[count], line);

    printf("%s\n", line1[count][i]);


    count++;

   }

   return(0);
}
```

(This is my updated code, it still prints the first line and then seg faults.)

when I compile and run this code, it prints the first line of the text file and then returns "segmentation fault"

Comment: You never initialize `count`. Turn on your compiler warnings and heed them. Also... er... Have you not learned about `strcpy()` yet?

Comment: @Shawn, thanks for the reply, I posted an updated code

Comment: *How to "store" STDIN*... So you want to use your 2D array as storage for everything you read from `stdin`? Fine, but horribly wasteful on storage for lines containing nothing but `'\n'` or text like `"okay"`. You also need to limit the number of lines you attempt to store to less than `MAXSIZE` lines.

Comment: Are you trying to count distinct words ? what about multiple words per line ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the question code is close.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  #define MAXSIZE  500
  #define MAXWORDS 1000

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    char line[MAXSIZE];
    char line1[MAXWORDS][MAXSIZE];
    int  count = 0;

    while(fgets(line, MAXSIZE, stdin))
      {
      printf("%s", line);
      strcpy(line1[count], line);
      printf("%s\n", line1[count]);  // instead of: printf("%s\n", line1[count][i]);

      count++;
      }

    return(0);
    }
```

Comment: `while (count < MAXWORDS && fgets(line, MAXSIZE, stdin))` You should also trim the trialing `'\n'` from `line` before copying to `line1[count]`. Using `line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;` is a simple and reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `strcpy` works as it should, but the `printf` caused a warning already at compile time, change the `printf`-line from    `printf("%s\n", line1[count]);` to `printf("%s\n", line1[count]);`

After the while loop you can verify your copy with:

```
for (int i=0; i < count; i++){
    printf("%d: %s",i, line[i]);
}
```

Although `fgets` will put a terminating `0`-byte at the end of the buffer, it would be more defensive to user `strncpy` which is guaranteed not copy more than n-bytes, but in this example you could eliminate the copy altogether by writing directly in to `line[count]` buffer.

**Also you shod take care and stop reading before overwriting your buffers.**
When you call `fgets` you limit the read to `MAXSIZE` which is good but you should also check count is below `MAXWORDS`